# jQuery multiple data decoding on server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

**Scenario:**

I have a `jQuery.ajax` call that is submitting three arrays to the server for saving to the database. I need to decode that combined data object that is being transferred to the server back into three arrays.

The server runs in `php`

If the scenario is ambiguous, what I am asking, how do you split the `$input` back into three arrays again. (This is on the `php` side.)

**Expected results:**

Breaking the object back into three seperate arrays for processing.

**Current results:**

Internal Server Error when I start to process the first array.

**Note before we get to the code:** I am still learning, please any tips/pointer are always welcomed.

**Code:**

*`jQuery.ajax`*

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "save_all.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { grades: JSON.stringify($scope.grades), commutators: JSON.stringify($scope.commutators), sGrades: JSON.stringify($scope.sGrades)},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

*`save_all.php`*

```
    <?php

        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

        $grades = $input["grades"];
        $commutators = $input["commutators"];
        $sGrades = $input["sGrades"];
```

Comment: 1) Don't you have a better exception than Internal Server Error (stack trace, inner exception, ...)? 2) Can you post the HTTP Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have JSON as the entire POST data, you have URL encoded key/value pairs, of which the values are JSON, so you don't need to access the raw POST data. Each of your JSON strings are in the standard `$_POST` array.

PHP:

```
$grades = json_decode($_POST['grades']);
$commutators = json_decode($_POST['commutators']);
$sGrades = json_decode($_POST['sGrades']);
```

Note: the `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax request refers to the response data type, not the request.

Comment: Whoops...didnt see your answer. Ill delete mine :)